# How do I remove the navigation arrow for tiles when used in a AppPart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using promoted links within a page.  I have 4 tiles within the  promoted links.  I can clearly see all 4 tiles on the page.  However, a left and right navigation arrow display I assume to allow me to scroll thru each tile to the left and right.  Since I can clearly see each tile this is not necessary and more importantly it is removing valuable height space.

I am hopeful I can remove this annoyance. Note if I use only 3 tiles then these navigation arrows no longer display.  Thus, I am puzzled why adding a 4th tile adds the navigation arrows when the 4th tile is clearly visible.

Comment: The arrows appear for scrolling, yes. Have you considered how hiding them might affect the usability for users with different screen resolutions? Or if you re-size your browser's window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be something to do with the width for the web part that sets the navigation arrows to visible or invisible. You could try to see if you can set it to a fixed width and see if it solves it.

Or you take the easy way and add a script editor webpart with some CSS to hide the navigation.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-promlink-button {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can remove navigation arrows by setting "display:none" for "promlink-button",

but we can also style the tiles by setting its **body width** and **background color** like below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-promlink-body {width: 100%;}
.ms-promlink-header{display:none;}
.ms-tileview-tile-content{background-color:#E5E5E5}
</style>​​
```

Comment: Worked well. Thank you very much for this.